# How to rename elements in an array based on the length of said array? (In the Unity Inspector)

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, inspector

I'm trying to create a procedural animation engine. Because I'm using the cross product to calculate the orientation of the body, the legs need to be in a specific order in the array.

I want to make sure it is intuitive for anyone that uses it, so ideally, I would like it to rename the elements in the inspector based on the length of the array.

Example:
[ideal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEBwK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of stuff is achieved by implementing a [`CustomEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) or also a [`CustomPropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html)

Let's e.g. say your class looks like

```
public class DynamicLegList : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LegStepper[] Legs;
}
```

Then you could achieve something like you showed via e.g.

```
// Since the UnityEditor namespace is completely stripped of during the build process 
// this should be placed in a folder called "Editor"
// or if using Assemblies this should be placed in a separate Assembly which
// is excluded from any platform except the UnityEditor itself
[CustomEditor(typeof(DynamicLegList))]
internal class DynamicLegListEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty legs;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        legs = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(DynamicLegList.Legs));
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> legNames = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>
    {
        {
            2, new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                {0, "RightLeg"},
                {1, "LeftLeg"},
            }
        },
        {
            4, new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                {0, "FrontRightLeg"},
                {1, "FrontLeftLeg"},
                {2, "BackRightLeg"},
                {3, "BackLeftLeg"}
            }
        }
    };


    private int count;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawScriptField();

        serializedObject.Update();

        legs.isExpanded = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(legs.isExpanded, legs.displayName, true);
        if (legs.isExpanded)
        {
            EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
            {
                EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
                {
                    count = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Size", legs.arraySize);
                }
                if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                {
                    if (count == 1 || legNames.ContainsKey(count))
                    {
                        legs.arraySize = count;
                    }
                }

                if (legs.arraySize == 1)
                {
                    var leg = legs.GetArrayElementAtIndex(0);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(leg, new GUIContent("Leg"));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (legNames.TryGetValue(legs.arraySize, out var names))
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < legs.arraySize; i++)
                        {
                            var leg = legs.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
                            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(leg, new GUIContent(names[i]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void DrawScriptField()
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        {
            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour((DynamicLegList) target), typeof(DynamicLegList), false);
        }
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works awesome! my last question (and rather a noob one) is how would I use this from another script, other than "Dynamic Leg List"

Comment: @FaffyWaffles you wouldn't ;) You would need to implement this again for each different component type. Or as said you could rather make it a `PropertyDrawer` then you can have the same field type in multiple components